# Algorithm analysis for ternary computer vs other based binary, 4th based 5th based

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, cpu-architecture, computation-theory

When I analyze algorithms, I suddenly asked this question to myself, if we had ternary computer time complexity would be cheaper ? or is there any base that we can build computers so that time complexity analysis would not matter ? I could not find much on the internet, but ternary based computer would process it much faster with given same resources.

I would appreciate any thoughts in this questions

Comment: Would changing the base ever make more than a linear change in actual time?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, possibly on topic at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

- No, the theoretical complexities of virtually all algorithms would remain the same in big-O-notation, since they don't depend on number representation: they just assume certain basic operations such as addition or multiplication take O(1) steps.
- For practical considerations, maybe some very narrow area dealing with base-3 representation itself would get an up-to-linear boost. Much like nowadays, getting the number of set bits in an integer has its own fast instruction (POPCNT) in modern processors, so it can be considered O(1).
- To get a feeling of what it takes for a new computing technology to wreak havoc on algorithm complexities, read about [quantum computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer).